# Show number of users in groups, even empty groups

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to pull out the information about each user group, while counting the number of users in each.
The counting works, however if a group does not contain any users, it does not retrieve the information - it simply gets ignored.

This is my query:

```
 SELECT
       g.*,
       count(u.username) as total,
       u.usergroup
  FROM
      usergroups as g,
      users as u
  WHERE
      u.usergroup = g.g_id
  GROUP BY
      g.group_name
```

This is a part of my "users" and "user groups" tables:

```
 Sample usergroups table structure
  +--------------------------+---------------+
  | Field                    | Type          |
  +--------------------------+---------------+
  | g_id                     | int(10)       |<- the user group's ID.
  | group_name               | varchar(255)  |<- the name of the user group
  +--------------------------+---------------+

  Sample users table structure
  +--------------------------+---------------+
  | Field                    | Type          |
  +--------------------------+---------------+
  | id                       | int(10)       |<- the user ID
  | username                 | varchar(255)  |<- the username
  | usergroup                | int(10)       |<- ID of the user group the user is in
  +--------------------------+---------------+
```

I have no idea what I have missed - but then again, I am very new to more complex queries (if you can call it that).

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a `left join`, and you're doing an `inner join`:

```
 SELECT
       g.*,
       count(u.username) as total,
       u.usergroup
  FROM
      usergroups as g
      left join users as u on
           g.u_id = u.usergroup
  GROUP BY
      g.u_id,
      g.group_name
```

Now that I have your attention, I'd like to take a minute to discuss what join conditions are. See, when you're first learning MySQL, they teach you the syntax you use. And hey, it works great, for certain sets of problems. Unfortunately, it causes you to equate "join condition" with "where predicate," and that's a problem.

In this case, we're saying, "Hey, MySQL, grab me all the stuff out of the `usergroups` table, and try to find a match to the `users` table where the `u_id` column from `usergroups` equals the `usergroup` column from `users`. If you can't find anything, that's okay, bring the `usergroup` back anyway, and just null out the columns that `users` brings to the table."

Previously, you were saying, "Hey, MySQL, grab me all the stuff out of the `usergroups` and the `users` table, but only where the `u_id` column from `usergroups` matches the `usergroup` column from `users`."

If you had done it with `inner join` syntax, like so:

```
 SELECT
       g.*,
       count(u.username) as total,
       u.usergroup
  FROM
      usergroups as g
      inner join users as u on
           g.u_id = u.usergroup
  GROUP BY
      g.u_id,
      g.group_name
```

You would have been saying, "Hey, MySQL, grab me everything from the `usergroups` table, and then go find everything in the `users` table where `u_id` equals `usergroup`. If you don't find a match, I don't want to see that usergroup show up in the results.

So, to be clear, the where predicates *filter* the result set, whereas the join conditions *map* one table to another.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about doing a left join.
Will give it a try and report back :).

Cheers.

Comment: Perfect! - Left Join was the answer :) - Cheers!
Will mark this as the answer once I can.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Makes a lot more sense now. Eric, thank you soo much for taking you time to elaborate!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN here instead of your implicit INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT
       g.*,
       count(u.username) as total,
       u.usergroup
  FROM
      usergroups as g
  LEFT JOIN users as u ON g.g_id = u.usergroup
  GROUP BY
      g.group_name
```